# Generate Date Time offset

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have DateTimeOffset input param. Need to create other DateTimeOffset param which Month is 2 month less than from input:

```
//DateTimeOffset  input;
DateTimeOffset modified = new DateTimeOffset(input.Year,
input.Month - 2, input.Day,
input.Hour, input.Minute,
input.Second, input.Millisecond,
input.Offset);

I get an exception
```

> Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.

What is wrong? - the month is 4. S0 4-2 = 2 is valid
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the month is a red herring, it's probably more likely your day is above 28 which means you are trying to create a date like 30th Feb (which doesn't exist!).

Use the [AddMonths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.addmonths%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead

```
DateTimeOffset modified = input.AddMonths(-2);
```

Comment: @Yakov - This is the correct answer, but also realize that you may need to adjust the offset afterwards.  It's possible that a different offset may apply if the time zone you're working with uses daylight saving time and you cross a transition.